# After Upgrade from 13.04 to 13.10 missing user in login screen

Tags: unity, upgrade, lightdm, login-screen

I have upgraded to 13.10 from 13.04 now after booting (even after updates and rebooting) my user id is not listed.  It has a uid higher than the minimum in lightdm.conf.  I have the user light display manager , guest , and remote login options in the login screen but not my ususal user id that I have been using from ubuntu 9 something.  It is a normal user and an administrator so that I could authorize drivers, updates, etc...  I do not have any custom display manager setup. It has been standard unity since unity was available.  I can login to my account by logging in as guest opening a termial and using su - user  Any insight would be appreciated.  Thanks